# Why is the IContentEvents.LoadedContent event fired multiple times for a page?

Tags: episerver

I've added an event handler for the LoadedContent event. I'm a bit surprised that the event seems to fire multiple times for a page during a single load. Why does that happen?

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IContentEvents>().LoadedContent += this.EPiServerApplication_LoadedContent;           
}
```

**EDIT**

I'm using EPiserver 8.

With "a singe load" I mean going from DOPE mode to edit mode for a page that is a child but has no children. Last time I counted the event fired 17 times for that page.

Comment: Perhaps there's code retrieving the page in multiple places, either explicitly or through GetChildren etc? Also, you should wire up the event in an InitializableModule instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The LoadedContent event is fired every time Get/TryGet on the IContentLoader (or IContentRepository) is called. This happens regardless if the data is loaded through from the cache or from the database.

As these APIs are used by many separate code branches, especially in edit mode, this event will be triggered multiple times just as you have found. Normally this should not be anything that you need to be worried about unless of course you are doing something resource intensive in your event handler.